# How to customize AWS Serverless Image Handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was following this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/overview.html) to deploy the AWS Serverless Image Handler. I used the given template, and I was able to successfully deploy it.

However, I want to customize the code slightly for my specific needs, and I tried two different approaches, but none of them worked.

**Approach #1**

1. I downloaded the .zip source code from the Lambda console, I unarchived it, made the changes, and deployed it via S3 (because it was over 50 MB I couldn't directly from my machine).
2. However, this resulted in the following error: `The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-central-1'`

**Approach #2**

Then I tried following the guide from their site: [Customizing Lambda Thumbor Package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/appendix-i.html)

1. First problem is, they recommend an Amazon Linux for the listed operations which I don't have, and the instructions for installing it rather complex.
2. At the end of the process, they say to use the command `aws s3 cp . s3://mybucket-[region_name]/serverless-image-handler/v1.0/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.zip"`. However, this results in the error `upload failed: Unable to locate credentials`.
3. To fix that, I tried running `aws configure`, but here I got the following error: `./serverless-image-handler-ui.zip to s3://my-bucket-eu-central-1/serverless-image-handler/v10.0/serverless-image-handler-ui.zip An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist`. I am suspecting that it's confused by the name of my bucket which uses the `-` separator the same as one separating the bucket name with the region in the command `aws s3 cp . s3://mybucket-[region_name]/serverless-image-handler/v1.0/ ...`

I just want a simple way to upload my customized code. How do I do that?

Comment: Hello, do you need deal with it still?